# Is there a way to only move one selected GridView item at a time?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a `GridView` which shows a list of slides which can be shown in a presentation.  I want the user to be able to select the slides to show and move the slides around to set the order to show them in.  Everything works except when moving a selected item.  Instead of only moving the one item, all selected items are moved.

Is there a way to set the `GridView` so that moving a selected item only moves the one item and not all the selected items?

For example: if I have slides 2, 4, and 6 selected I can move slide 3 to any new position and only slide three will be moved (the other slides would be shifted to fill the hole, but you get the idea).  If I move slide 4, slides 2 and 6 will be moved to the new location also.  I only want 1 slide to move at a time.

```
<CustomControls:GridView x:Name="slideGridView" AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DefaultGridViewItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Slides}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SlideDetailsTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</CustomControls:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty clear. The functionality of the control is also pretty clear. The answer, and I am sorry to be the one to give it, is no. When you reorder in the GridView you are instructing the control to reorder all the items selected. You would need to change your selection mode in order to get closer to your desired goal. Again, sorry.

Best of luck!